# Query is searching all user records instead of just mine

Tags: php, search, join

I am doing this search engine that should only search my content, but in search results its also searching other users contents which is private.  New to PHP and need help! thanks!

```
        $sql = "SELECT client_visit.why, client_names.client_name,
        client_names.client_id, client_visit.notes, 
        client_visit.date_time, client_visit.v_id FROM 
        client_visit LEFT JOIN client_names ON 
        client_visit.client_is = client_names.client_id 
        WHERE client_visit.user_id = '$pid' 
        AND client_visit.why_visit LIKE '%$q%'
        OR client_visit.field1 LIKE '%$q%' 
        OR client_visit. field2 LIKE '%$q%' 
        OR client_visit. field3 LIKE '%$q%' 
        AND client_visit. field4 LIKE '%$q%' 
        OR client_visit. field5 LIKE '%$q%' 
        OR client_visit.v_notes LIKE '%$q%' 
        OR client_visit.date_time LIKE '%$q%'
        OR client_names.client_name LIKE '%$q%' 
        ORDER BY client_visit.id DESC LIMIT $start, $limit";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
  $sql = "SELECT client_visit.why, client_names.client_name,
            client_names.client_id, client_visit.notes, 
            client_visit.date_time, client_visit.v_id 
            FROM client_visit 
            LEFT JOIN client_names ON client_visit.client_is = client_names.client_id 
            WHERE ( client_visit.user_id = '$pid' )
                   AND
           ( client_visit.why_visit LIKE '%$q%'
            OR client_visit.field1 LIKE '%$q%' 
            OR client_visit. field2 LIKE '%$q%' 
            OR client_visit. field3 LIKE '%$q%' 
            AND client_visit. field4 LIKE '%$q%' 
            OR client_visit. field5 LIKE '%$q%' 
            OR client_visit.v_notes LIKE '%$q%' 
            OR client_visit.date_time LIKE '%$q%'
            OR client_names.client_name LIKE '%$q%'
            ) 
            ORDER BY client_visit.id DESC LIMIT $start, $limit";
```

Use the parenthesis to group your conditions.

Comment: ok that worked! but how come just paranthesis made a difference?

Comment: Basically it doesn't interpret the logic in the way you think it does :) Think of like in maths, where you can group operations together to be done in groups: (3 + 4) * 2 is 14, but 3 + 4 * 2 is 11. It's a similar case here, it's doing some operations in a different order to you.

Answer (score 2):

Group your logic into brackets, so the query really is doing what you think it is.

```
WHERE client_visit.user_id = '$pid' 
AND
(
    client_visit.why_visit LIKE '%$q%'
    OR client_visit.field1 LIKE '%$q%' 
    OR client_visit. field2 LIKE '%$q%' 
    OR client_visit. field3 LIKE '%$q%'
)
AND
(
    client_visit. field4 LIKE '%$q%' 
    OR client_visit. field5 LIKE '%$q%' 
    OR client_visit.v_notes LIKE '%$q%' 
    OR client_visit.date_time LIKE '%$q%'
    OR client_names.client_name LIKE '%$q%'
)
```

On another note, I'm hoping your data is being escaped. If not, you want to put this just before `$sql = ...` to give it some protection.

```
$pid = (int) $pid;
$q = mysql_real_escape_string($q);
$start = (int) $start;
$limit = (int) $limit;
```

Comment: It's called casting, and it forces the variable to be converted to an integer (whole number). So if I managed to somehow make $pid contain "6 OR 1" it's truncate it to 6.